# luatex: latelua execution order, effect on enclosing nodelist, and its inner workings

Tags: luatex, performance, shipout

In my musings on luatex, perhaps like alice in the wonderland, the one thing that is not quite clear is the inner workings of latelua. As I understand, all of the material to be output on a page is built and stored as (perhaps separate, perhaps deep) nested linked lists of tex 'node's. Also, AFAIK latelua places its contents into its enclosing linkedlist as a  node that is to be processed later in execution time (hence the prefix "late"). The latelua code is executed when a nodelist containing it is going to appear on a page, which means it can be many pages later & probably executed as many times the containing nodelist is to appear in the document. Also, to add to the awesomeness, nodelists can be split or joined to form new ones before placing them again on some other page. So here are a bunch of related questions: How is the information about latelua nodes maintained in luatex engine? Is there a special data structure that deals with them (perhaps for performance?). Like some coloring scheme with a table: Lets say, for instance when a latelua node is encountered, a flag is set in its parent node, and carried upstream when luatex execution moves back to parent node. Such scheme would have to honor nodelist splits and joins. Or is that there is no separate data structure... and right before shipping contents to page luatex traverses the entire nested nodelist of the contents that are to go on that page and checks if there is a latelua node that it must execute (this time around)? If it is so, i.e. no separate special data structure for latelua nodes, and entire nodelist to be shipped out is traversed, is it because luatex anyway needs to completely traverse nodelist that is to appear on the page? If yes, then why does it traverse entire nodelist right before shipout? Is there a way to ask the shipout process to grab some pre-baked pdf page contents (that are ready to shipout, and ask it to not traverse) and get better performance? If yes, then how can one do that? It's a generally accepted norm to ask one question at a time, though here I am breaking the norm as the questions I ask are close knit, and it could be more beneficial for readers (as there is no English language book on luatex).

Comment: the difference between directlua and latelua is the same as the difference between `\write` and `\immediate\write` in both cases the text is stored in a whatsit node and executed on shipout

Comment: Thanks, maybe I should have commented a little about my background... I am one of those who has jumped directly into luatex, with little background in traditional tex (though have used latex extensively in past, will read more about `\write` and `\immediate\write`). Though your comment doesn't sound 100% accurate, as not all of directlua store text as whatsit node. One cannot look at a nodelist and say if any of its contents were generated using directua, though one can look at a nodelist and say if  latelua was encountered as it adds a special latelua node, there is no special directua node.

Comment: you misread my comment. \directlua and \immediate\write do not make whatsit nodes, they execute immediately. write and latelua do nothing at the point they are entered other than store the argument as text in a whatsit. (I posted an answer with a bigger example)

Comment: it is _much_ simpler than you suggest here there are no special flags or pre-scans to find these nodes. the latelua node is found and executed in just the same way and at the same time as the character node containing a is found and converted to the pdf string for that character, while tex is traversing the output box and making pdf or dvi output.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I do actually understand that difference between directua, and latelua. Cool that answers one of my question. One more question I ask is if one can access & store resultant pdf elements of a nodelist (post nodelist translation into pdf elements) and then pass it to luatex to avoid another traversal and translation of nodelist into similar pdf elements? Note this is different from the performance gain of avoiding to build same nodelist again and again by building it once and saving in a box. Its performance one would gain from avoiding translating nodelist to pdf contents again.

Comment: not using classic tex but in luatex you can in principle take over the entire box to pdf generation using the callbacks. `finish_pdfpage` callback may be your friend here, Note these callbacks are fragile beasts poking in to luatex's pdf generation process and more or less undocumented it is a hook that you can hook into but you probably need to have a good feeling for the luatex source code to know where you are and what it is safe to change at these points.

Answer (score 2):

The mechanism is exactly the same as `\write` in classic TeX (with `\immediate\write` being like `\directlua`)

Consider

```
\documentclass{article}

\showoutput
\showboxdepth3
\begin{document}

a

\write20{write 1}

b

\latelua{print 'latelua 2'}

c

\immediate\write20{immediate write 3}

d

\directlua{print 'directlua 4'}

e

\end{document}
```

This produces the terminal output

```
immediate write 3
directlua 4

Completed box being shipped out [1]
```

showing that at this point the two non-immediate forms have not been executed  but the two immediate forms have.

Then TeX starts to process page 1 converting the box node structure to the PDF output, the terminal shows the box node structure

```
Completed box being shipped out [1]
\vbox(633.0+0.0)x407.0, direction TLT
.\glue 16.0
.\vbox(617.0+0.0)x345.0, shifted 62.0, direction TLT
..\vbox(12.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 12.0fil, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x345.0, direction TLT
..\glue 25.0
..\glue(\lineskip) 0.0
..\vbox(550.0+0.0)x345.0, glue set 491.94745fil, direction TLT
...\write-{}
...\glue(\topskip) 5.52
...\hbox(4.48+0.11)x345.0, glue set 325.0fil, direction TLT []
...\write-{write 1}
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.95
...\hbox(6.94+0.11)x345.0, glue set 324.44fil, direction TLT []
...\latelua0{print 'latelua 2'}
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.41
...\hbox(4.48+0.11)x345.0, glue set 325.56fil, direction TLT []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 4.95
...\hbox(6.94+0.11)x345.0, glue set 324.44fil, direction TLT []
...\glue(\parskip) 0.0 plus 1.0
...\glue(\baselineskip) 7.41
...\hbox(4.48+0.11)x345.0, glue set 325.56fil, direction TLT []
...\glue -0.11
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\glue 0.0
...\glue 0.0 plus 0.0001fil
..\glue(\baselineskip) 23.34
..\hbox(6.66+0.0)x345.0, glue set 170.0fil, direction TLT
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
...\TU/lmr/m/n/10 1
...\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil
```

Where you see that the write node and the latelua node are still whatsit nodes in the box, just containing the unevaluated text from the supplied argument.

```
...\write-{write 1}
```

and

```
...\latelua0{print 'latelua 2'}
```

Then latex reads the font map as shown on the terminal

```
{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
```

and finally as it writes the PDF it comes to the write and latelua nodes and executes their contents and the terminal shows

```
write 1
latelua 2
```